# How to reorder the methods of hpp/cpp file automatically through an IDE/code editor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Usually I have to manually reorder the methods in both .h and .hpp files of a class based on public/protected/private and keeping related methods together.

However, while defining those methods in .hpp/.cpp files it is hard to follow the same order.
I understand that reordering the class declarations (.h files) manually makes sense, but a good IDE should be able to reorder the class definitions automatically.

Consider for example:

class declarations (inside A.h file)

```
class A {
 public:
   int x();
   float y();
 private:
   std::string z();
};
```

class definitions (inside A.cpp file)

```
std::string A::z()
{
   return "hello world";
}
float A::y()
{
   return 5.0/9 * (100-32);
}
int A::x()
{
   int x = 1;
   int y = 2;
   return x+y;
}
```

As you can see, class definitions are out of order (A.cpp). I see manually reordering definitions as a waste of time, and would be happy if IDE does that for me.

The code editor I prefer is VS Code, is there any plugin or setting available in VS Code that can do this for me?
If this feature is available in some other IDE, please post that as well, I may consider using it.

Please note that I want to keep order of definitions exactly same as declarations. In the above case, first x, then y, then z should come in A.cpp

Comment: there is no reason/advantage to have a particular order in the `.cpp` file, the same for the `.h` file, what to do if the names of your methods in alphabetical order does not make sense

Comment: I order the methods in a CPP file alphabetical because that makes manual searching easier.  I group methods in the class declaration by `public, protected`, then `private`.  Methods within the groups are sorted alphabetically.  I'm usually pedantic enough to sort members alphabetically.

Comment: Unless you need to order functions to avoid forward declarations, any other ordering is for human readers of the code. If you're nice to humans, they're generally nice to you. Those humans that aren't should be destroyed before the infection spreads and society collapses.